# Nargin function in R (number of function inputs)

Tags: r, matlab, arguments, environment

## Goal

I am trying to create a function in R to replicate the functionality of a [homonymous MATLAB function](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) which returns the number of arguments that were passed to a function.

## Example

Consider the function below:

```r
addme <- function(a, b) {
    if (nargin() == 2) {
        c <- a + b
    } else if (nargin() == 1) {
        c <- a + a
    } else {
        c <- 0
    }
    return(c)
}
```

Once the user runs `addme()`, I want `nargin()` to basically look at how many parameters were passed―2 (`a` and `b`), only 1 (`a`) or none―and calculate `c` accordingly.

## What I have tried

After spending a lot of time messing around with environments, this is the closest I ever got to a working solution:

```r
nargin <- function() {
    length(as.list(match.call(envir = parent.env(environment()))))
}
```

The problem with this function is that it always returns 0, and the reason why is that I think it's looking at its own environment instead of its parent's (in spite of my attempt of throwing in a `parent.env` there).

I know I can use `missing()` and `args()` inside `addme()` to achieve the same functionality, but I'll be needing this quite a few other times throughout my project, so wrapping it in a function is definitely something I should try to do.

## Question

How can I get `nargin()` to return the number of arguments that were passed to its parent function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
nargin <- function() {
  if(sys.nframe()<2) stop("must be called from inside a function")
  length(as.list(sys.call(-1)))-1
}
```

Basically you just use `sys.call(-1)` to go up the call stack to the calling function and get it's call and then count the number of elements and subtract one for the function name itself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution and the explanation. I wasn't aware of `sys.call`, it looks like something I might be using more often from now on. Cheers!